# Rethinkdb change feed rendering with jQuery

Tags: jquery, socket.io, rethinkdb

I'm currently trying to figure out how to use the change feed from RethinkDB.

I have a table called `Calls` and upon the insertion, deletion, and updating of it, I would like to stream the changes.

Right now, I have the function to load calls initially and then return changes:

```
r.db('test').table('Calls').run(function(err, cursor) {
    if (err) throw err;
    socket.emit('load calls', cursor);
});

r.db('test').table('Calls').orderBy({index: r.desc('call_number')})
.changes().run(function(err, cursor) {
    if (err) throw err;
    cursor.each(function(err, record) {
        socket.emit('load calls', record);
    });
});
```

and on the frontend I append the HTML to the page:

```
socket.on('load calls', function(docs) {
    docs.map((call) => {
    $('.calls-list').append(`
    <tr id="call_${call.call_number}">
      <td>${call.call_number}</td>
      <td>${call.time}</td>
      <td>${call.type}</td>
      <td>${call.status}</td>
      <td>

     </td>
      <td>${call.location} - ${call.location_cross}</td>
      <td>${call.notes}</td>
      <td><a id="update-call-${call.call_number}" href=""><i class="edit icon yellow text"></i></a> <a id="archive-call-${call.call_number}" href=""><i class="delete icon red text"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
`);
    }
});
```

The problem here is that the appended HTML is more or less permanent and "independent" from the database; I would like it to be real time and dependent on the database change feed just like in [this video](https://youtu.be/dabkH3bUXHI?t=1m20s).  In that case, the database insertion and the orderBy was instant.  So in my current problem, if somebody wanted to delete a call, then I would have to emit a socket event and delete the respective HTML element by referencing the ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I am understanding your question correctly, but I will try and address a few things. First of all, the documents that get returned when you call the changefeed are different from when you call `r.db.table` (your first call). Your first call will return all the "Call" documents from the database, but the change feed returns a document that includes the previous "Call" document and the new "Call" document. For example, when a new "Call" is added to the database you would see the following:

```
{
    old_val: null,
    new_val: {id: 1, call_number: x, time: y, ...}
}
```

For an update to an existing "Call" you would see:

```
{
    old_val: {id: 1, call_number: x, time: y, ...},
    new_val: {id: 1, call_number: x2, time: y2, ...}
}
```

And when a "Call" is deleted you would see:

```
{
    old_val: {id: 1, call_number: x2, time: y2, ...},
    new_val: null
}
```

You are going to have to handle each scenario differently. You can do this in your frontend by checking to see if there is and old_val and/or a new_val in each document. Something like this:

```
socket.on('load calls', function(docs) {
    docs.map((call) => {
        if (! call.old_val && ! call.new_val) {
            // this is a call returned from from r.db.table, not the changefeed
            // add call to the dom
        }
        else if (! call.old_val) {
            call = call.new_val;
            // this is a new call added to the db and returned from r.db.table.changes
            // add call.new_val to the dom
        }
        else if (! call.new_val) {
            // this is a delete - remove the row from the dom
        }
        else {
            // this is an update - update the existing row
        }
    }
});
```

Or you can do some level of filtering on the server and emit different events to the client. Something like this:

```
r.db('test').table('Calls').orderBy({index: r.desc('call_number')})
.changes().run(function(err, cursor) {
    if (err) throw err;
    cursor.each(function(err, record) {
        if (! record.old_val) {
            // new call added
            socket.emit('load calls', record);
        }
        else if (! call.new_val) {
            // call deleted
            socket.emit('delete calls', record);
        }
        else {
            // call updated
            socket.emit('edit calls', record);
        }
    });
});
```

Then on the client you would subscribe to each event:

```
socket.on('load calls', function(docs) {
    // add docs to dom
});

socket.on('edit calls', function(docs) {
    // update docs in dom
});

socket.on('delete calls', function(docs) {
    // delete docs from dom
});
```

Hope this helps. FYI, I'm the author of the video/sample app you referenced : ) Thanks for watching!